# How do I unlock the Distant Friends Achievement?

Tags: into-the-breach

One of the last achievements I have to unlock is the "Distant Friends" achievement. Most other achievements have a description explaining what you have to do to unlock them, but this one is pretty vague. I looked it up online and it sounds like it involves breaking specific mountains... but the details are not clear to me. How do I unlock this achievement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The achievement is unlocked by recruiting one of the three secret pilots,

> each from a different race in FTL: a Mantis, a Rockman, and a Zoltan.

Unlike regular pilots, these can only be encountered in special pods, not regular Time Pods or as a Perfect Island bonus. A special pod can be triggered to drop during a mission by picking up a beacon hidden inside an ice tile or a mountain tile.

A beacon [can be seen under cracked ice or inside a cracked mountain](https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/922547668365000712/AD919C2BA1AA0D8D5A2E2326346DE7273A168161/), and the tile it's in may or may not be damaged at the beginning of a mission. Once broken free, the beacon must be picked up by a mech, which will trigger the pod to drop at the end of the turn. Protect the pod until the end of the battle and it will be opened as usual.

Comment: Wow, never noticed this. I'm going to go beacon hunting tonight!